# UISplitViewController - event when the master view is hidden in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

When my splitViewController is in portrait mode, I would expect the delegate method willHideViewController to be invoked when I dismiss the master view by touching the detail view. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`willHideViewController` will only be called when orientation changes.

However, you can setup a delegate to the `UIPopoverController` that is responsible for showing and hiding the master view in portrait mode. You can set up the delegate in this method: `- (void)splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:popoverController`.

Once the delegation is in place, the methods in `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol will get invoked every time user dismisses the master view in portrait mode.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html for delegate methods.